# Why is my ajax request repeating same data from Laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

**Goal:** load more rows from the database to a view using an `ajax` request when a user clicks the "load more" button. I would like the data to load without a page reload.

**Problem:** The data being loaded via `ajax` keeps repeating the same rows on every request and doesn't paginate as per standard request.

**Detail:** I have a view that loads 4 rows from the database which I paginate using `Laravel's` built-in `pagination`. I've added an event listener on a "load more" button which successfully sends the request to the `controller`, which in turn successfully returns data. The `controller` returns a partial view of the data I want to display. However this data doesn't seem to increment properly and keeps repeating the records shown on each request. I am not sure what I am missing here, if the problem is in the `controller` or in the `JS`?

I am not very experienced with `Laravel`, `PHP` and `JS` since coming from more of a web designer and `UI` design background and would love to really understand what I am doing wrong here.

**PLEASE NO JQUERY EXAMPLES.**

**Partial view:**

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div style="background-color:pink; width: 200px;">
        <p>{{ $product->title }}</p>
        <img src="/images/product/{{ $product->img }}" alt="{{ $product->title }}" style="width: 50px;">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Javascript:**
(I am updating the button href attribute so the request URL reflects the correct query)

```
const container = document.querySelector('#sandbox-container');
let button = document.getElementById('load-stuff');
let url = button.getAttribute('href'); // http://127.0.0.1:8000/sandbox?page=2
let pageNum = button.getAttribute('href').substr(35,1);

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    // if page loads successfully, replace the number at the end of the url with the incremented page number
    pageNum++;
    newUrl = url.replace(/page=([^d]*)/, `page=${pageNum}`);
    button.setAttribute('href', newUrl);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {  
            container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xhr.responseText);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Request failed, this is the response: ${xhr.responseText}`);
        }
    };     
    xhr.send();     
})
```

**Controller:**

```
public function sandbox(Request $request)
    {      
        $products = Product::orderBy('title', 'asc')->paginate(4);

        if($request->expectsJson()){
            return view('sandbox-more', compact('products'));
        } else {
            return view('sandbox', compact('products'));
        }  
    }
```

Comment: `button.getAttribute('href').substr(35,1)` is a terrible way to get the pageNum. What if you are on page 10, what if the URL changes or you add https and now your pageNum is `=`. Have you seen `{{ $products->links() }}` in use on `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination`. That generates links to the other pages.

Comment: Laravel has great documentation. If you are on 5.8 then I suggest reading `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination`. There is a specific section called `Customizing The Paginator URI` where you should pass in 'withPath' if you want to use a URL as you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this snippet for your javascript

```
const container = document.querySelector('#sandbox-container');
let button = document.getElementById('load-stuff');

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let url = button.getAttribute('href');
    let pageNum = button.getAttribute('data-page-number') || 0;

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    // if page loads successfully, replace the number at the end of the url with the incremented page number
    pageNum++;
    newUrl = url + '?page=' + pageNum;

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {  
            container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', xhr.responseText);
            button.setAttribute('data-page-number', pageNum);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Request failed, this is the response: ${xhr.responseText}`);
        }
    };     
    xhr.send();     
})
```

What I've done here is to have the page number saved to a dedicated custom attribute "data-page-number". Doing "button.getAttribute('href').substr(35,1)" is inefficient. And then check the page number and increment it on the button's click event. Also, only update the "data-page-number" attribute when the request has been successful. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate the pagination every time you make a request to get the correct data. [Here](https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902) is a very good example on doing it via `jQuery`. Should just adjust it to your needs since you are using pure `Javascript`.

Comment: I am sure I am doing that already? I am grabbing the href with `let url = button.getAttribute('href');` then I grab the next page with `let pageNum = button.getAttribute('href').substr(35,1);` and then I increment it (`pageNum++;`), replace the number bit in the url (`newUrl = url.replace(/page=([^d]*)/, `page=${pageNum}`);`) and finally set the attribute to the new query string     button.setAttribute('href', newUrl);